# iPhone and Mac connection through Bonjour

Tags: iphone, macos, bonjour

I have a task in that i want to import and export csv files from iphone to mac. I have used the Zero configuration network bonjour.In that i want to export file from iPhone to mac.In my mac the bonjour server is running.How to select a directory for the exported file should be save in that path.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use an instanceof `NSSavePanel`:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html